# Substitute for FeedBurner's "sending the feed to Twitter" feature?

Tags: twitter, feeds, feedburner

I am using FeedBurner to send my feed to this Twitter account:  http://twitter.com/#!/rbloggers.

I see that it stopped working about a month ago.

Is there an alternative service I could use?

Comment: What software to you use to create your feed (e.g. blogging platform)? There might be some plugins.

Comment: Wordpress - you are right I didn't think of that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/) seems promising, although I haven't tried it yet. It even lets you manage the format of the tweets and supports post filters.

[image: twitterfeed]

There are also a few plugins for Wordpress such as [WP to Witter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-to-twitter/) and [WordTwit](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordtwit/). For Wordpress.com you can use [Publicize](http://en.support.wordpress.com/publicize/) which is included by default.

Comment: tweeterfeed is great! I've used it for many years now